# How to show the curves are conics.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, self-learning

Solve the equation

$$\frac{dx}{x^2+b^2} =\frac{dy}{xy-bz}=\frac{dz}{xz+by}$$

How to show the curves are conics.

First of all , I need to find its integral curves.

I tried to solve. But I get strange results. So I cannot write there. Sorry. Please show me way. Thanks

I found one solution.

$$\frac{xdy+bdz}{x^2y-bxz+bxz+b^2z}=\frac{dx}{x^2+b^2}$$

Then I get $bz=c_1$

Comment: Conics are planar curves. But you use x,y,z, so you're not in planar geometry. What is $c_1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

which integrals do you need?
these?

$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+b^2} =A=\frac{1}{b} \left(- \frac{i}{2} \log{\left (- i b + x \right )} + \frac{i}{2} \log{\left (i b + x \right )}\right)$

$\int \frac{dy}{xy-bz}=B=\frac{1}{x} \log{\left (- b z + x y \right )}$

$\int\frac{dz}{xz+by}=C=\frac{1}{x} \log{\left (- b y + x z \right )}$